# Problema ao alternar entre gráficos usando CardLayout

Tags: java, layout

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao utilizar CardLayout para exibir os gráficos de duas classes. Eu pretendia mostrar cada gráfico de uma vez e exibir o outro ao apertar um botão, no entanto quando eu aperto o botão o primeiro gráfico continua desenhado e o segundo aparece sobre escrevendo o primeiro, fazendo com que os dois gráficos apareçam ao mesmo tempo.

**Classe principal**

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    JPanel mainCard;
    JButton jb1, jb2;
    CardLayout cards;
    NRZL card1 = new NRZL();
    NRZI card2 = new NRZI();

    public MainFrame(){
        setSize(900,900);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Tela de escolha");

        jb1 = new JButton("Vá para NRZI");
        jb2 = new JButton("Vá para NRZL");

        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cards = (CardLayout) mainCard.getLayout();  
                cards.show(mainCard, "card 2");
            }
        });

        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cards = (CardLayout) mainCard.getLayout();
                cards.show(mainCard, "card 1");
            }
        });

        card1.add(jb1);
        card2.add(jb2);

        mainCard = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        mainCard.add(card1, "card 1");
        mainCard.add(card2, "card 2");

        getContentPane().add(mainCard);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

**Classe gráfico 1**

```
public class NRZL extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.repaint();
        g.drawOval(200, 200, 200, 200);        
    } 
}
```

**Classe gráfico 2**

```
public class NRZI extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.repaint();
        g.drawRect(300, 200, 200, 200);
    }

}
```

Desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc pode colocar um repaint

```
jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          repaint();
          cards = (CardLayout) mainCard.getLayout();  
          cards.show(mainCard, "card 2");


      }
  });

  jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        cards = (CardLayout) mainCard.getLayout();
        cards.show(mainCard, "card 1");

      }
  });
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, esse era o detalhe que faltava.